# Directory.GetFiles() with C: and C:\

Tags: c#

I'm simply using `Directory.GetFiles()` to get all files in that directory.

What I found out is, that `C:` as a parameter is giving back all files which are in my release folder (at least it seems so).

`C:\` gives me the real `C:\`folder like I assumed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "C:" (with no backslash) is not a valid path URL. Using it will then return your project folder.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger -- but if you try it with a drive letter that doesn't exist, it throws an exception.  Why does it work with "c:"?

Comment: You can use "C:" as a reference to your project folder.

Comment: This is a good question which shouldn't be down voted.  @ShannonHolsinger -- don't you think that's a little esoteric?  See king_nak answer with this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths

Comment: @rory.ap, I spend 2 minutes already trying to find duplicate.. no luck.

Comment: idk - it has to be something. If it is esoteric, it's not as weird as some of the other stuff floating around in the lexicon.

Comment: It's not a programming question. It's a file system question.

Comment: Yea, cause who ever works with a filesystem while programming.  Sheesh.

Comment: @jdl134679 Programmers also work with hardware. That doesn't mean hardware questions are a good fit for SO. Get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`C:` refers to the current directory on the `C` drive, which happens to be your release folder. `C:\`  refers to the root directory on the `C` drive.

You can also use paths like `C:..\test.txt` which is a relative path to the current directory on `C`, or `\test.txt` which is an absolute path on the current drive

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) about naming files and paths for details

Comment: I had no idea C: was even valid, let alone refers to the current working directory.

Comment: Is the current directory the last used one? And is it stored in a cache somewhere?

Comment: @FredMy It's the same as the current working directory on that volume. This C: stuff has been around since the beginning of DOS. Current working directory a couple of decades before that.